# Checking multiple DOM values

Tags: jquery, arrays

In jQuery I have the following array:

```
var arr = [{ "id" : "txt1", "value" : 180 }, { "id" : "txt2", "value" : "Text"}];
```

On the keyup event I want any of these text fields to check if all the fields have the corresponding value from the array.

How can I do this most efficiently?

Comment: Do you have control over the structure of the array? If so, putting the data in a single object with the `id` as the property name would be much easier

Comment: I have control over how the "var arr" is built, as it is built in a for() loop

Comment: Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/518cor44/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the array and bind event handler based on the id.

```
// iterate over the array elements
arr.forEach(function(v) {
  // get element using the id selector and then bind 
  // keyup event for listening
  $('#' + v.id).keyup(function() {
    // compare the current value with array element value
    if (this.value == v.value) {
       // do the rest of code
    }
  })
})
```

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "txt1",
  "value": 180
}, {
  "id": "txt2",
  "value": "Text"
}];

arr.forEach(function(v) {
  $('#' + v.id).keyup(function() {
    if (this.value == v.value) {
      console.log('matched');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" />
<input id="txt2" />
```

---

Or generate a helper object which holds id as property name and value as it's value. On click event get the value from the array using id property of the element.

```
// object for holding corresponding value based on id
var obj = {},
  // variable for selector
  sel;

// iterate and generate object and selector
sel = arr.map(function(v) {
  // add object property
  obj[v.id] = v.value;
  // return id selector
  return '#' + v.id;
  // combine the id selectors
}).join();


// bind keyup event
$(sel).keyup(function() {
  // compare the current value and correponding array object value
  if (this.value = obj[this.id]) {
    console.log('matched');
  }
})
```

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "txt1",
    "value": 180
  }, {
    "id": "txt2",
    "value": "Text"
  }],
  obj = {},
  sel;

sel = arr.map(function(v) {
  obj[v.id] = v.value;
  return '#' + v.id;
}).join();

$(sel).keyup(function() {
  if (this.value == obj[this.id]) {
    console.log('matched');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" />
<input id="txt2" />
```

Comment: Almost works. I think I know how I can implement "AND" relationship between array values, but how can I implement "OR"?

Comment: @LemonCake : what you mean by __OR__?

Comment: well if one fields has the value 180 or the other "Text"
you can set value relations like "AND" , "OR" and others I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var exist = false;
selectors = [];
$.each(arr,function(i,v) {
  selectors.push('#'+v.id);
});
selectors = selectors.join(',');
 $(selectors).keyup(function() {
     $.each(arr,function(i,v) {
       if($('#'+v.id).val() == v.value) { exist = true}
     });
     if(exist) {alert('at least one element has value from array')}
  });
```

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "txt1",
  "value": 180
}, {
  "id": "txt2",
  "value": "Text"
}];

var exist = false;
selectors = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, v) {
  selectors.push('#' + v.id);
});
selectors= selectors.join(',');

$(selectors).keyup(function() {
  console.log(selectors)
  $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
    if ($('#' + v.id).val() == v.value) {
      exist = true
    }
  });
  if (exist) {
    alert('at least one element has value from array')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" />
<input id="txt2" />
```